# Delete rows in a Core Data table view

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am trying to make the deletion of rows with core data working. I actually have a table view but when I click the delete button on a row it remains darked and nothing more happens.

Here is the code I use to delete the row:

```
- (void) controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

you can delete the row like this....

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject 
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type 
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete) {
        // Delete row from tableView.
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```